# Cancellation property of kernel in singular integral

Tags: harmonic-analysis, singular-integrals

Suppose that the limit
\begin{equation*}
        \text{p.v.}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\frac{\Omega(x-y)}{|x-y|^n}f(y)dy 
    \end{equation*}
exists for almost every $x\in \mathbb{R}$ for all $f \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Here, $\Omega \in L^1(S^{n-1})$ and for any $\lambda >0$, $\Omega(\lambda x) = \lambda \Omega(x)$. Show that $\int_{S^{n-1}}\Omega d\sigma=0$.

I try to express the integral as
$$ \int_{S^{n-1}} \Omega(y') \int_0^\infty f(x-ry')\frac{dr}{r} d\sigma(y') $$
and use some particular choice of $f$ to arrive at a contradcition if the cancellation property $\int_{S^{n-1}}\Omega d\sigma=0$ is not satisfied.

Comment: This question could use a " can someone provide a hint", or "How can I proceed further". Overall it seems to lack a question and is in the direction of being closed.